# How to randomly choose what code should be run?

Tags: java

Is there a way to randomly pick what code should run other than how I have it here? There's gotta be an easier way. I know about switch and case but didn't know if I could randomly have a case there.

```
 Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(4);

        if (i == 0) {
            //dosomething
        } else if (i == 1) {
           // dosomethingelse
        } else if(i == 2) {
            //dosomethingelse
        } else if(i == 3) {
            //dosomethingelse
        } else if(i == 4) {
            //dosomethingelse
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is already pretty optimal, at least for how you would do something like this in Java.  As a pointer, you could rewrite your logic to use a `switch` statement, which would at least make the code a bit easier to read:

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(5);

switch(i) {
    case 0:
        // do something
        break;
    case 1:
        // do something else
        break;
    case 2:
        // do something else
        break;
    case 3:
        // do something else
        break;
    case 4:
        // do something else
        break;
}
```

Note: If you want to generate a random integer between 0 and 4 (inclusive of the 4), then use `nextInt(5)`.  Using `nextInt(4)` will never actually generate the value 4.

Comment: I actually didnt even realize that with the bound, thanks. And nice, I haven't done a ton with switches so looks good. Thank you